# what is the type signature of `Func` in gen_server:start/4?

Tags: erlang, gen-server

The OTP docs say the signature for `gen_server:start/4` is this:

```erl
start_link(ServerName, Module, Args, Options) -> Result
ServerName = {local,Name} | {global,GlobalName}
  | {via,Module,ViaName}
 Name = atom()
 GlobalName = ViaName = term()
Module = atom()
Args = term()
Options = [Option]
 Option = {debug,Dbgs} | {timeout,Time} | {hibernate_after,HibernateAfterTimeout} | {spawn_opt,SOpts}
  Dbgs = [Dbg]
   Dbg = trace | log | statistics | {log_to_file,FileName} | {install,{Func,FuncState}}
  SOpts = [term()]
Result = {ok,Pid} | ignore | {error,Error}
 Pid = pid()
 Error = {already_started,Pid} | term()
```

https://erlang.org/doc/man/gen_server.html#start_link-4

What is `Func`? The docs just say:

> This function is useful when a more complex initialization procedure is needed than the gen_server process behavior provides.

So now I know it is useful. But how many arguments does it take? Of what types?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Func` in that spec is an option for `debug`, so it has little to do with that doc.

The doc you have quoted refers to the `gen_server:enter_loop` function, not to `Func`.

Regarding your question, `Func` is handled with the `sys` module, like in [sys:install/2](http://erlang.org/doc/man/sys.html#install-2), and has the following [spec](http://erlang.org/doc/man/sys.html#type-dbg_fun):

```erlang
 dbg_fun() =
    fun((FuncState :: term(),
         Event :: system_event(),
         ProcState :: term()) ->
            done | (NewFuncState :: term()))
```

Answer (score 0):

If I follow the source on the latest master, the file for [gen_server](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/40922798411c2d23ee8a99456f96d6637c62b762/lib/stdlib/src/gen_server.erl#L181-L213) doesn't have any mention of `install` as any of the `debug` options.

So I guess

1. The code has changed and the documentation is not up-to-date
2. The code and documentation has changed but the latest documentation is not deployed

And from the history, it could be what "@Jose M" is referring to.

Comment: the file for gen_server doesn't mention `install` because `gen_server:enter_loop/4` (like all other public gen_server functions) is missing a spec. The quasi-specs (using different syntax) are from the XML documentation.

You can tell the syntax is different because real specs use `::` in constraints instead of `=`